# Address of externed array differs between compilation units

Tags: c, arrays, extern, pebble-sdk

I have an array `foo` declared in a C file, which is then declared as `extern` in the corresponding header. I then access `foo` from another file, but the address of the first element in the array is an invalid address, and differs from that in the compilation unit where `foo` is defined. This has been built from the Pebble SDK, using ARM CodeSourcery compilers.

Example code:

### test1.h

```
extern int foo[];
void testRoutine();
```

### test1.c

```
#include <pebble.h>
#include "test1.h"

void testRoutine()
{
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Hello World! foo: 0x%x", (unsigned int)&foo[0]);
}

int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

### main.c

```
#include <pebble.h>
#include "test1.h"

int main()
{
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Start of test");
    testRoutine(); // Print the address of foo from the perspective of test1.c
    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "foo: 0x%x", (unsigned int)&foo[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Start of test
Hello World! foo: 0x12345678
foo: 0x12345678
```

Actual output:

```
Start of test
Hello World! foo: 0x20081234
foo: 0x21941234 (placeholders, I can't get the real addresses right now)
```

This code works as expected in standard x86 GCC, but does not work on the ARM compiler. Have I messed up the code, or is there a compiler bug here?

Comment: It might have something to do with that you declare an array of unknown size, meaning the linker might think it's different from the definition of the array which have a size. If you both declare and define the array with a fixed size, it might work better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - thanks, I will try when my internet starts working again (on phone internet :/). I thought that declaring the array like that was valid though? In any case, the "wrong" address is the same across all foreign compilation units, so that behaviour could well be going on.

Comment: This cannot possibly happen unless your compiler is non-standard.

Comment: @n.m. - as in, it's a compiler bug? I'll report this as a bug to the relevant people if so.

Comment: What are sizeof(unsigned int) and sizeof(int*) on your platform?

Comment: @Étienne - it's a 32-bit platform. I've not checked `sizeof(unsigned int)`, but `sizeof(void*)` is 4. Given the output, and the lack of compiler warnings, I'm assuming `sizeof(unsigned int)` is also 4.

Comment: Side note: You should use `"%p"` in order to print an address.

Comment: Side note #2: Have you tried declaring `extern int foo[5];` instead?

Comment: @slugonamission Okay, on a 32 bits platform I don't understand why that would happen.

Comment: @barakmanos - not yet, that's the next test. My home internet has just died though, so I can't test right now.

Comment: It's either a compiler bug or your bug. I would suspect the latter, because a compiler bug of such proportions would go unnoticed for  about 1.5 milliseconds. Make sure you are running code you think you are running. Also, you can `printf` pointers directly, without casting (use `printf ("%p", ptr)`), make sure you use this in your bug report.

Comment: @n.m. - that's what I'd have thought. I'll clean up the test case and ensure that other tasks on the system (no memory protection :( ) aren't interfering with it.

Comment: @barakmanos - declaring the size of the array leads to identical results.

Comment: @n.m. - I've removed all other tasks, declared the size of the array and fixed the prints and the bug still persists. I'll report this further up. Cheers :).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem without success on Debian 64 bits:

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

int main()
{
    testRoutine(); // Print the address of foo from the perspective of test1.c
    printf("foo: 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)&foo[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

test1.h:

```
extern int foo[];
void testRoutine();
```

test1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "test1.h"                                                    

void testRoutine()                                                    
{                                                                     
    printf("Hello World! foo: 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)&foo[0]);        
}                                                                     

int foo[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

The result is:

```
$ ./program 
Hello World! foo: 0x600970
foo: 0x600970
```

However gcc warnings are explicit:

```
test1.c:7:38: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

You should try with:

```
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "foo: 0x%p", &foo[0]);
```

Edit:
Since you said you are running it on a 32 bits platform where sizeof(unsigned int)==sizeof(int *), the cast is not the problem. There is some other problem in your program unrelated to this code (stack corruption?).

Comment: I got basically identical output on 64-bit Ubuntu. The casting *shouldn't* be an issue on the actual platform, since it's a 32-bit platform (although I should get into the habit of using `%p`). In any case, trying to use the returned address leads to the program crashing.